Change TextView.textSize become too big value
・I want to chnage TextSize by code.
・TextView is in Dialog.
and when click the addButton, Textsize is increment.
this is all code in dialog.
 private fun detailDialog(data: String) {
        Dialog(requireContext()).apply {
            val db = SkillDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(db.root)
            val data = AllData.skillList.firstOrNull { it.skill_name == data } ?: return
            db.apply {
                var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
                val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
                scope.launch {
                    val input = URL(data.skill_photo[0].photo_URL).openStream()
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    }
                }
                detail.text = data.skill_instruction
                skillName.text = data.skill_name
                close.setOnClickListener {
                    cancel()
                }
                add.setOnClickListener {
                    println(detail.textSize)
                    if (detail.textSize < 40f){
                        var currentValue = detail.textSize
                        detail.textSize = currentValue + 0.5f
                        println(detail.textSize)
                    }
                }
                sub.setOnClickListener {
                    if (detail.textSize > 20f){
                        detail.textSize -= 0.1f
                    }
                }
            }
            setCancelable(false)
        }.show()
    }

・I tried add TextSize value in this code.
  add.setOnClickListener {
                    println(detail.textSize)
                    if (detail.textSize < 40f){
                        var currentValue = detail.textSize
                        detail.textSize = currentValue + 0.5f
                        println(detail.textSize)
                    }
                }

・this is logcat in textSize
37.0
98.4375

Why textSize is became too big?
How can I do that?
